# How to get a break time for the days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table

```
ID Date Time

001 12/01/2011 08:00:00
001 12/01/2011 08:30:00
001 12/01/2011 11:30:00
001 12/01/2011 12:35:00
001 12/01/2011 03:30:00
001 12/01/2011 04:30:00
002 12/01/2011 08:30:00
002 12/01/2011 09:30:00
....
```

I want to select intime, outtime, breakouttime, breakintime from table

```
Select id, date, min(time) as intime, max(time) as outtime from table group by id, date
```

the above query is working for intime and outtime, but i want to select the break outtime and break intime for the dates.

For Example BreakOut time is between 11:30:00 to 12:30:00 means then query should check the time from min(Punchtime) and max(Punchtime) between 11:00:00 to 01:00:00.

Expected Output

```
Id Date intime outtime breakout breakin

001 08:00:00 04:30:00 11:30:00 12:35:00
002 08:30:00 09:30:00 null null 'so there is no punches between 11 to 1 for the break time, so break time should be null
```

How to make a query for the above condition

Need query help

Comment: How do you know 11:30 and 12:35 are the break in and break out times?  Why not 8:30 or 3:30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that break times are always between 11:00 AM and 1:00 PM, you could do something like below.  Basically, use a CTE to fabricate an extra "BreakTime" column based on some logic.

To make the query work with your data which is shown in 12-hour time, I made the (poor) assumptions in the logic that anything between 11:00 and 13:00, or 0:00 and 1:00 are break times.  In your real system, you should use 24-hour times so you don't have the AM/PM ambiguity.  Furthermore, I'm not sure you need 2 separate columns for date and time.

But anyway, since this is just sample code to show the query, I left it alone.

Here's a complete example, with a test table and your data:

*** Updated to use derived table for SQL 2000 instead of CTE ***

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    ID nvarchar(5),
    MyDate date,
    MyTime time
)

insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('001', '12/01/2011', '08:00:00')
insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('001', '12/01/2011', '08:30:00')
insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('001', '12/01/2011', '11:30:00')
insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('001', '12/01/2011', '12:35:00')
insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('001', '12/01/2011', '03:30:00')
insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('001', '12/01/2011', '04:30:00')
insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('002', '12/01/2011', '08:30:00')
insert into MyTable (ID, MyDate, MyTime) values ('002', '12/01/2011', '09:30:00')

select 
    ID, 
    MyDate, 
    min(MyTime) as intime, 
    max(MyTime) as outtime,
    min(BreakTime) as break_intime, 
    max(BreakTime) as break_outtime
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
        CASE 
            WHEN (MyTime > '11:00:00' and MyTime < '13:00:00') THEN MyTime
            WHEN (MyTime > '0:00:00' and MyTime < '1:00:00') THEN MyTime
            ELSE null
        END AS BreakTime
    from MyTable 
) as DerivedTable
group by ID, MyDate
```

And the output:

```
ID  MyDate  intime  outtime break_intime    break_outtime
001 2011-12-01  03:30:00.0000000    12:35:00.0000000    11:30:00.0000000    12:35:00.0000000
002 2011-12-01  08:30:00.0000000    09:30:00.0000000    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: CTEs aren't available in SQL Server 2000 but looks easy to replace with a derived table.